# What does it mean to say that a topology is defined by a metric?

Tags: general-topology

I have read the following phrase. The weak topology on $X$ is defined by a translation invariant metric. What does this mean? Does this mean that the weak topology is the same as the topology that the metric induces?

Comment: It means that the weak topology **isn't** the same as the topology that a metric of this type induces.

Comment: Oops. Ok thanks! Edited for clarity.

Comment: Your interpretation is plausible, but without more context, it's hard to say whether it's correct. Where does the metric come from?